# Trying to model behavior change by manipulating my bootstrapping

Tags: bootstrap

I am working on revising a sales compensation plan and want to simulate various possible future scenarios. To do this I am using an empirical distribution + bootstrapping against 30K real sales transactions. I've got pretty much everything worked out except for introducing behavior change and measuring how that affects profit and growth.

Here's the list of changes I am going to model:

1. If we surcharge a particular type of client (reduced commission if you work on them)
2. If we scale commission based on size of contract

Both of these are somewhat zero sum, e.g., if one chooses to prioritize sales opportunities based on #2 it will effect other sales opportunities. The incentive plan, on paper, will drive down "bad clients" and their opportunities via #1 and drive up good opportunities via #2.

My approach is to use a parameter called "incentive_response" to drive how strongly the sales teams respond to the incentive design and let that influence the resampling. E.g., a "very strong" incentive response might drive bad clients towards 0 (per #1) while a "weak" response may only reduce its representation by 5%.

My questions:

1. Is there a term for this? I find even knowing the correct term solves half of these problems because I can research online
2. What, if any, elegant ways to steer a resampling algo have you seen or used previously? I see a path to the answer if I brute force but I'm trying to get better at not relying on brute force.